# Moving from nested loops to NumPy iterating

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have a system of equations that I am trying to simulate and using very basic looping structures seems to rapidly slow down my computing speed. I have a mock example below to illustrate how I am running the simulation now:

```py
import numpy as np

Imax, Jmax, Tmax = 4, 4, 3 
Iset, Jset, Tset = range(0,Imax), range(0,Jmax), range(0,Tmax)

X = np.arange(0,48).reshape(3,4,4)
X[1], X[2] = 4, 2
Y = 2*X

for t in Tset:
    if t == 2:
        break
    else:
        for i in Iset:
            for j in Jset:
                Y[t+1,i,j] = Y[t,i,j] + X[t,i,j]
                X[t+1,i,j] = X[t,i,j] + 1



# Output for Y... 

array([[[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
        [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
        [16, 18, 20, 22],
        [24, 26, 28, 30]],

       [[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
        [12, 15, 18, 21],
        [24, 27, 30, 33],
        [36, 39, 42, 45]],

       [[ 1,  5,  9, 13],
        [17, 21, 25, 29],
        [33, 37, 41, 45],
        [49, 53, 57, 61]]])
```

Intuitively this structure makes sense to me because I am accessing the individual elements of the `Y` array and updating it, but because I have this looping over very large values and have more going on in the loop, I am experiencing a drastic reduction in computational speed.

I came across `nditer` and I am hoping that I can use this in place of the multiple nested loops that I have so that I can still get the same result, but faster. How can I go about converting this nested for-loop style into a more efficient iteration scheme?

Comment: `nditer` does not help with speed

Comment: Replace the inner 2 loops with `Y[t+1]=Y[t]+X[t]` and `X[t]+1`. You already use whole array operations with code like `2*Y` and X[0]=...`

Comment: Apart from basic vectorization you probably want to look into ODE solvers to be found in the `scipy.integrate` module.